# What is this char "DEL"? it's displayed in a ng-repeat loop on google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, ascii

This char look like this on google chrome.
[image: It look like this on google chrome]

And look like this on  mozilla
[image]

I don't know what is this char "DEL" [image]. Even google doesn't show any result pasting the char.

This is my html Code

```
<tr class="item-brand-col" 
                        ng-repeat="attributeCategoryToCompare in categoryAttributesToCompare">
                        <td class="table-title">
                            {{attributeCategoryToCompare.title}}<br/>
                        </td>

                        <td ng-repeat="productCompare in productsToCompare"
                                class="product-{{productCompare.id}}">
                                    <label ng-if="attributeCategoryToCompare.group === attributeProductToCompare.name"
                                        ng-repeat="attributeProductToCompare in productCompare.attributesDetail" ng-bind="attributeProductToCompare.value | join">
                                                    <!--{{attributeProductToCompare.value | join }}-->
                                    </label>
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
```

If some one know how remove it from DOM, I really appreciate this.

Comment: try backspacing stuff or using a smart editor and show non-printable chars.

Comment: with base on your comment, I deleted the break line and it doesn't appear any more. Nevertheless thank you